# Can BeautifulSoup find elements with a matching value?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraper for the first time, and I am using Beautiful Soup to parse a JSON file and return several attributes that I send to a CSV.

The `status` variable, in the JSON array, is a binary value (0/1). I'd like to return only arrays that have a 0 for status. Is it feasible to do that?

```
"""soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find()
print soup.prettify()"""
js_data = json.loads(html)
Attraction = []
event = []
status = []
for doc in js_data["response"]["docs"]:
    Attraction.append(doc["Attraction"])
    event.append(doc["PostProcessedData"]["Onsales"]["event"]["date"])
    status.append(doc["PostProcessedData"]["Onsales"]["status"])
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    datas = zip(Attraction,event,status)
    keys = ["Attraction","event","status"]
    f.write(";".join(keys))
    for data in datas:
        f.write(",".join([str(k).replace(",",";").replace("<br>"," ") for k in data]))
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: What you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Add the html and what you are trying to get, also why are you using bs4 to parse json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but maybe this helps:

```
for doc in js_data["response"]["docs"]:
    if doc["PostProcessedData"]["Onsales"]["status"] == "0":
        Attraction.append(doc["Attraction"])
        event.append(doc["PostProcessedData"]["Onsales"]["event"]["date"])
        status.append(doc["PostProcessedData"]["Onsales"]["status"])
```

Comment: Can you change `== 0:` to `== "0":`, and I'll accept your answer? Just had to make that small tweak, and it works correctly now. Thanks!